# Error creating bean with name '...RedisHttpSessionConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I'm using Redis and created `HttpSessionConfig` file. Here is my code in

**`HttpSessionConfig.java`:**

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionStrategy() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.authenticationInfo();
    }

}
```

And here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
    <!-- Redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I got error:

> ```
> Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration':
> ```
>
> Initialization of bean failed

More trace:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [bookstore/config/HttpSessionConfig.class]: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory]:
>   Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/lettuce/core/KeyValue
>
> ```
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> ```
>
> creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [bookstore/config/HttpSessionConfig.class]: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory]:
>   Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/lettuce/core/KeyValue

Anyone know how to fix it ???

Comment: Please, provide the full stack trace.

Comment: I already edited my post! Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the stack trace the error tells that

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/lettuce/core/KeyValue

So  add manually the dependency [io.lettuce](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.lettuce/lettuce-core/5.1.7.RELEASE) in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
    <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```